# SP2013 App icon not rendered, only App link is displayed + how we can set the sliding transparent hover text over App icon?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am facing an App Icon related issue.
I am creating SharePoint Hosted App which I am deploying to SP 2013 Developer site.

By default any app will have the AppIcon set under Images folder. Also it is referred in AppManifest.xml.

I am able to deploy my app successfully and it works fine, **but I don’t see the icon/image for the App. All I see is a link of the name of the app.**

I have tried another image/Another App, but every time I see the link only.

Any one have any idea on that??

Also curious to know **how we can set the  sliding transparent hover text over App icon??**

Answer (score 0):

I have got the icon displaying for app.
Actually in Sp2013 developer site, **by design** you will see link only after app deployment. 
**But once you see the site content location, you will be able to see the recently installed App with proper Icon.**

Still looking for answer on:
**how we can set the sliding transparent hover text over App icon??**